# ClassCastException NativeRegExpExecResult cannot be cast to NativeArray

Tags: java, multithreading, nashorn

I am developing an app on WildFly 10 running on OpenShift, utilizing Nashorn to do server-side rendering of a React app.

The app runs ok on my local machine (i don't like perf levels), but when I deploy it to OpenShift, something mysterious happens.

After a couple of requests, code that ran find on previous requests suddenly starts throwing

> java.lang.ClassCastException: jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeRegExpExecResult cannot be cast to jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray

The stack trace reveals this coming from a line of [code in React-Router](https://npmcdn.com/react-router@1.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js)... I added a couple of lines of logging to react-router manually and the strange thing is that the parameters that react-router is working on in the failing scenario. This is what the altered code looks like:

```
if (match != null) {
  if (captureRemaining) {if (typeof global != 'undefined') {global.log.warn('match.length=' + match.length);}
    remainingPathname = match.pop();
    var matchedPath = match[0].substr(0, match[0].length - remainingPathname.length);
    if (typeof global != 'undefined') {global.log.warn('remainingPathname=' + remainingPathname + ', matchedPath=' + matchedPath);}
    // If we didn't match the entire pathname, then make sure that the match
    // we did get ends at a path separator (potentially the one we added
    // above at the beginning of the path, if the actual match was empty).
```

(note the calls to `global.log.warn`... I added those)

If you look at the [full logs](http://pastebin.com/s4ZeeinP) you can see that for the first requests, things seem to be working fine, but then, suddenly, it starts throwing this `ClassCastException` and won't stop anymore. All my app does is return `503 service not available` for any request.

I messed around with the code, rewriting it multiple times to get correct behavior but I'm kinda stuck. In the end I stuck in a `synchronized` block to try to eliminate threading issues but the issue remains. Weird thing is, that if I set `max-worker-threads` to `1` in WildFly, the issue seems to disappear.

I say seems to because i find it very hard to pin down the problem, what with OpenShift's long deployment times and the 'random' behavior of the issue.

Below is the relevant code for my `ReactRenderFilter`. [Full code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/K8LvB1vL).

```
public class ReactRenderFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    private static final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType("text/javascript");  
    private static final List<CompiledScript> scripts = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<RenderEngine> renderEngine = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private FilterConfig config;
    private String bundlePath;
    private String jspPath;

    public static class RenderEngine {
        private final ScriptContext context;
        private final ReactRenderer renderer;
        private final long lastModified;

        public RenderEngine(File bundle) throws ScriptException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
            context = new SimpleScriptContext();
            Bindings global = engine.createBindings();
            context.setBindings(global, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
            global.put("global", global);
            for (CompiledScript script : scripts) {
                script.eval(context);
            }
            engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(bundle), "utf-8"), context);
            lastModified = bundle.lastModified(); 
            LOG.finer("Getting renderer");
            renderer = ((ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("global.render", context)).to(ReactRenderer.class);
        }

        String render(String path, String initialDataJSON) {
            return renderer.render(path, initialDataJSON);
        }

        boolean isOutdated(File bundle) {
            return lastModified != bundle.lastModified();
        }
    }


    public ReactRenderFilter() {super();}
    @Override public void destroy() {}

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        config = filterConfig;
        try {
            String[] paths = ...
            for (String path : paths) {
                if (path.trim().isEmpty()) {continue;}
                File file = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath(path.trim()));
                scripts.add(((Compilable) engine).compile(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8")));
            }
            bundlePath = config.getServletContext().getRealPath(config.getInitParameter(PARAM_APP_BUNDLE_PATH).trim());
            jspPath = config.getInitParameter(PARAM_MARKUP_JSP_PATH).trim();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException | ScriptException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Unable to initialize ReactRenderServlet.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        File bundle = new File(bundlePath);
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());
        String initialDataJSON = "{}";
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> initialData = (Map<String, Object>) req.getAttribute("initialData");
        if  (initialData != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            initialDataJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(initialData);
            req.setAttribute("initialDataJSON", initialDataJSON);
        }
        String renderResult = null;
        try {
            if (renderEngine.get() == null || renderEngine.get().isOutdated(bundle)) {
                // prevent multiple render engines to be instantiated simultaneously
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    renderEngine.set(new RenderEngine(bundle));
                }
            }

            // I sure hope there is a way around this... locking on central object
            // during rendering can't be good for performance... But it beats having
            // only one worker thread
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                renderResult = renderEngine.get().render(path, initialDataJSON);
            }

            if (renderResult.startsWith(MARKUP)) {
                String markup = renderResult.substring(MARKUP.length());
                req.setAttribute("markup", markup);
                int maxAge = 60 * 60; // 60 minutes 
                res.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
                res.addDateHeader("Expires", new Date().getTime() + maxAge);
                req.getRequestDispatcher(jspPath).forward(request, response);       
            }
            else if (renderResult.startsWith(REDIRECT)) {
                String url = renderResult.substring(REDIRECT.length());
                res.sendRedirect(url); 
            }
            else if (renderResult.startsWith(NOTFOUND)) {
                int maxAge = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 365 days 
                res.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
                res.addDateHeader("Expires", new Date().getTime() + maxAge);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            else {
                String msg = renderResult.substring(ERROR.length());
                throw new ServletException("Unable to generate response for route [" + path + "]: " + msg);
            }
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have one static `ScriptEngine` and a separate `ScriptContext` + `Bindings` for each thread (in a `ThreadLocal`)... I thought (based on docs I found) that this should be thread-safe... In desperation I added a `LOCK` and `synchronized` blocks on this lock, but it doesn't seem to help.

I am not sure it is even related to threading, but it sure does so.

**Does the above code look like the right way to create multiple script contexts to be used concurrently?**

**Any tips to get rid of this issue, or even to debug it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears similar to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145550 which has been fixed in jdk9 and backported to jdk8u-dev ( http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn/rev/fa7dce1af94e ). It'd be great If you can pull http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn and build nashorn.jar to test against your app. Thanks.

Comment: Wow that sure looks like it. Unfortunately, my project has a deadline on jan. 1st and, due to this bug, I had to abandon Nashorn. I am now running my ReactJS code on Node JS... I hope you can understand I have no time to go back to Nashorn now. I am hoping to be able to return to Nashorn in the future though. Thank you very much for this answer! I asked on the Nashorn dev. list but no one there could help me.

Comment: Too bad that you had to move because of project deadline. Hopefully, you'll use nashorn in future! Thanks for reporting the issue via nashorn-dev as well as here.